# How to prove $u_{xy}=u_{yx}$?

Tags: calculus, analysis

Given that $v=v(x,y)$ has a continuous first-derivative, $u\left( x,y \right) =xv+y\phi \left( v \right) +\psi \left( v \right) $, $\phi,\psi$ are differentiable, and
$$
x+y\phi '\left( v \right) +\psi' \left( v \right) =0.
$$
prove that
$$
\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial x^2}\cdot \frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial y^2}-\left( \frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial x\partial y} \right) ^2=0.
$$

---

My work: $u_x=v+xv_x+yv_x\phi '+v_x\psi '=v$, $u_y=xv_y+\phi +yv_y\phi '+v_y\psi '=\phi$, and if $u_{xy}=u_{yx}$,then
$$
\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial x^2}\cdot \frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial y^2}-\left( \frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial x\partial y} \right) ^2=v_xv_y\phi '-v_y\cdot v_x\phi '=0.
$$
That demands $u_{xy}=v_y$ and $u_{yx}=v_x\phi'$ are continuous.

---

My question: Obviously $u_{xy}=v_y$ is continuous, how can I prove $u_{yx}=v_x\phi'$ is continuous?

Comment: Is it $x+y\phi'(v)+\psi(v)=0$, or is it $x+y\phi'(v)+\psi'(v)=0$ ?

Comment: Is it $\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial x^2}\cdot \frac{\partial ^2y}{\partial y^2}-\left( \frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial x\partial y} \right) ^2=0$ or is it $\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial x^2}\cdot \frac{\partial ^2 v}{\partial y^2}-\left( \frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial x\partial y} \right) ^2=0$ ? And what were you computing in LHS?

Comment: Sorry, it has been corrected. $x+y\phi'+\psi'=0$ and $u_{xx}\cdot u_{yy}-(u_{xy})^2=0$.